# How to quote some special words (registry numbers) to be not tokenized with Spacy?

Tags: python-3.x, spacy

I have some numbers inside text which I would like to stay as one sentence. Some of them:

```
7-2017-19121-B
7-2016-26132
wd/2012/0616
JLG486-01
H14-0890-12
```

How can I protect them to be not separated on words. I already use regex for custom tokenizer to never split words with dashes but it works only with letters not with numbers. I don't want to change the default regex which is big and very complicated. How can I do it easily?

What I have done already is using those "hyphen protector". For `7-2014-1721-Y` I got tokens `[7,-,2014,-,1721-Y]`, so last phrase is not divided but the previous are. As I said the code is complicated and would like to add the same to include such action for number-number entity.

This is the function:

```
def custom_tokenizer(nlp):
    prefix_re = compile_prefix_regex(nlp.Defaults.prefixes)
    suffix_re = compile_suffix_regex(nlp.Defaults.suffixes)
    # changing default infixed
    def_infx = nlp.Defaults.infixes    
    cur_infx = (d.replace('-|–|—|', '') for d in def_infx)
    infix_re = compile_infix_regex(cur_infx)

    return Tokenizer(nlp.vocab, prefix_search=prefix_re.search, suffix_search=suffix_re.search,
                                infix_finditer=infix_re.finditer, token_match=None)
```

Maybe there's some easier way except moditication? I've tried to quote these "plates" with some escape characters like `{7-2017-19121-B}` but it doesn't work.

By the way, there's a regex which matches these special "numbers". Maybe workaround for me will be just removing them from the text (which I'll try later) but now I'm asking if I have any chances here.

`["(?=[^\d\s]*\d)(?:[a-zA-Z\d]+(?:/[a-zA-Z\d]+)+)", "(?:[[A-Z\d]+(?:[-][A-Z\d]+)+)"]`

Hint. I found out changing from `7-2017-19121-B` to `7/2017/19121/B` works as needed. The question is (for me to check) how can I adapt this to my current code and stay with the performance I have now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add them as ["special cases"](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#special-cases):

```
nlp.tokenizer.add_special_case("7-2017-19121-B", [{ORTH: "7-2017-19121-B"}])
...
nlp.tokenizer.add_special_case("H14-0890-12", [{ORTH: "H14-0890-12"}])
```

Test:

```
print([w.text for w in nlp("Got JLG486-01 and 7-2017-19121-B codes.")]) 
# => ['Got', 'JLG486-01', 'and', '7-2017-19121-B', 'codes', '.']
```

Comment: Thanks for some idea. The problem is I need the same performance (on very tiny loss) because I work with millions of records. Here is calling tokenizer every sentence... Maybe not problem, anyway, I'll try your example.

Comment: @Peter.k Well, that is spacy way. If you have a regex that matches the words and you want to use it with `re.sub`, go that way. If you have issues with the regex, I will be glad to help.

Comment: It works and I use it for now., Something slows down but hard to benchmark the project at current stage.